# How to disable/enable all entries in a channel?

Tags: search, resave

I have a channel named Parts. And there are 160k+ entries in it. I originally imported them into the channel using the "Feed Me" plugin. But none of the entries will show up in search results unless I re-enable the entry.

Each entry says it's enabled, but the entry won't show up in search results unless I first disable it, save it, then re-enable and save it.

I've tried re-saving the section in the control panel to trigger a mass resave. But that didn't do the trick. I see there is a resave command option for the craft console, but I don't know how to use it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So really your question is not how to disable/enable all entries in a section, it's how to rebuild your search index. Look here:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/searching.html#rebuilding-your-search-indexes

```bash
php craft resave/entries --section parts --update-search-index
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly. Thank you